# Cap to completely cover internal bathroom ventilation (with option to remove later)

Tags: shower, vent

I recently moved into a house where the main bedroom has an en-suite bathroom. However, due to there being low pressure to the shower in there (a separate issue), I never use that bathroom. It's a small space, and has an open-air vent in the shower wall which is permanently open. Couple that with the sub-zero temperatures in the UK at the moment, and the fact that the already-large bedroom has very high ceilings (3.3m / 10.8 feet), it's absolutely *freezing* at night.

I'd like to use that en-suite bathroom at some point, once I've gotten around to resolving the pressure issue, so I don't want to permanently fill the vent hole; but it's definitely not going to be for a while, so in the meantime I'd like to cover it up completely.

[image: A silver plastic vent cover set against the wall, where you can clearly see the daylight on the other side]

(It's also worth noting that the vent itself is completely unsealed, and you can just spin it around on its axis; and if I hold my hand up to it, a *considerable* draft is coming in)

I've looked at magnetic vent covers (like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/MagX-Magnetic-Flexible-Anisotropic-Registers/dp/B07XG3D8Z8)), however the current vent cover is plastic, and it seems silly to replace it with a metal one purely so I can cover it up (also it is directly inside the shower cubicle, so arguably would be more liable to rusting).

It's also worth noting the outside of the vent is quite high up, so not easily reachable without a very, very long ladder or an industrial cherry-picker.

I've considered simply buying something like a neprene sheet, removing the vent and sticking that behind it to both cover the hole and seal it before putting it back in place - will that work as expected? Or should I be packing the hole out with something in addition?

**TL;DR:** Want to cover very drafty hole impermanently. Tips?

Comment: Can you remove that grille plate and show us what's behind?  Worst case, you stuff the area behind the grille with fiberglass insulation or something as a temporary measure.  Does the exterior vent have a flap?

Comment: @Huesmann As far as I can determine there's no flap on the exterior, but it is VERY high and awkwardly placed above a roof peak, so it would be nigh on impossible to reach without some specialised equipment. I like the idea of fibreglass insulation though, and my neighbour might have some spare.

Comment: stick a washcloth or folded pillow case onto it using  magnets to secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sealing the vent fan off should get you most of the benefit. There is additional benefit to insulating, of course, but stopping the air leak is the first and biggest item. If you can remove the cover, how about just taping a sheet of material to the back then putting the cover back on?

Comment: I've just tried this (although it was a hell of a job getting that cover back on!) - hopefully will see a decent difference from this, but the draft is virtually gone just from using a piece of card, which is encouraging.

Comment: Let us know how it goes. I bet you notice the difference quickly.

Comment: @indextwo if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote button next to _every_ answer that was helpful to you, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks - I do actually know how to use StackExchange, I just didn't have the chance to follow up _immediately_ yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the fan mechanism comes out clean, leaving just a 'tunnel' through the wall… a DIY hack…

Remove the fan assembly.
Spray the hole with WD40.
Put a strong bag - supermarket 'bag for life' - *halfway* down the depth of the hole.
Fill with 'foam & fix' type cyanoacrylate filler [loosely, it will expand to several times the initial volume.]
Once dry, cut any that blossomed out of the front to fit [make sure you save enough of the bag to be able to get a good grip later], then push the now solid, form-fitting bag further down the hole.
Replace the fan assembly.
When you wish to bring it back online, pull the bag & contents out again.

I have a disused cat-flap through the wall similarly filled.

Comment: This is a hell of a hack! I just took the cover off and it seems like it also has an entire THING surrounding the assembly, so it's more to do than I had anticipated on a Tuesday evening; but I've put some thick card and a disused flannel behind it to cover the hole initially, and I might see how feasible this is when I can take a proper look at how involved it is to remove properly.

Comment: This is pretty clever! Just don't push it to or past a joint in the duct - your foam may expand into the joint locking it in place, or the bag may tear when it hits the joint and then you're back here asking how to get a foam plug out of a duct! :)

Comment: If all goes wrong you can always hack it out in bits - it's not stuck to anything other than the bag.

Comment: @Tetsujin This is an ingenious solution, but for the sake of minimal effort on my part I've just gone with some neoprene sheeting to cover the hole for the moment. Definitely going to try this out in the future though - I've got an aircon vent in the bedroom which only gets used about 2 weeks in the year 